# Repo source for firmware-linux-nonfree?

Tags: repository, firmware

Which repository source do I need to add to my sources.list to access the package firmware-linux-nonfree?

I am using Deb 6 testing 32 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** add the `non-free` component to the line that defines the main Debian repository in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

`linux-firmware-nonfree` is in the `non-free` Debian component, so you should find the line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` that looks like `deb http://<some url here>/debian <distribution version> main [contrib]`, and add `non-free` somewhere after `main`. Then, to install, run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`.

If you are using oldstable or stable, you should also add `non-free` to the `security.debian.org` lines, if you have them enabled. If you like, you can do the same to both `deb-src` lines, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: The line that worked for me was `deb http://mirror.optus.net/debian/ testing main contrib non-free`. Thanks for pointing the way!

Comment: Debian 8 package name: `firmware-linux-nonfree`